# How to create a hover effect over two separate object?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

I have two div's, A and B. I would like to hover over DIV A and reveal DIV B, but I do not want DIV B to hide until the mouse moves from over DIV B.

```
<div id="a"><img src="images...." class="profile" id="options" /></div>
<div id="b"> //some information</div>
```

The jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#a').hover(function(){
$('#b').show();
},
function(){
$('#b').hide();
});
});
```

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.profile{ position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}
#id{ position: absolute; top: 20px; width: 300px; height: 400px;}
-->
</style>
```

I provided the css for explanation purpose. I was thinking of changing the class so that but DIV A and DIV B have the same class. This was not possible because my DIV B will become the size of a chatting image.

below is an image of what I am trying to describe:

[image: I want to hover over DIV A and reveal DIV B, DIV B should only be hidden when the mouse move from over both DIV A and DIV B]

can someone please explain where I am going wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#b').show();
  });

  $('#b').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: This answer is on the right track. When I tested it, it works. However I have to move the mouse over DIV B for it to be hidden again. I was thinking more along the line that when the mouse moves from over any of the DIV'S, DIV B disappear. Sorry if it was not clear before!

Comment: As stated in an answer below, if you want B to hide when mousing off of A, you can, but you MUST make sure A & B are connected.

Comment: See my edited answer below. You can achieve what you just explained above with CSS and no need for Javascript.

Comment: This answer work with a little help from Jan Dvorak. The css showed the link but the image was not linked. I adjusted the above code and I got my desired result. I made sure both div was together and then added both #a , #b to mouseenter and #b, #a to mouseleave. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT You can do the entire thing with CSS. See the updated JSFiddle link:
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk5dp/1/)

```
#a,#b {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
}
#b {
background: blue;
display: none;
}
#a:hover + #b {
display: block;
}
#b:hover {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to show B when cursor on A OR B and hide B when cursor leaves A AND B.

```
$("#a, #b").hover(
    function(){$("#b").show();},
    function(){$("#b").hide();}
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7akEc/

Also probably you can put B inside A and show/hide it with just css

```
#a:hover #b {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Your logic fails if there's a gap between `#a` and `#b` (as there seems to be from the screenshot)

Comment: DIV B is hidden. It will only appear when you hover over DIV A. However I want DIV B to remain until the mouse moves from over both A and B. The user just have to move the mouse down to select what will be placed in DIV B.

Comment: Oh, it is still not so clear what do you want, sorry :( Is my solution right but B should be visible on load? Can you edit post with instructions what should be on load, what on hover both blocks and what on leave?

Comment: Jan Dvorak, yes, you right there is limitation, but with provided css there is no gap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do?, Are you trying to show div #b when you h

```
    (function(){

      $('#a').hover(function(){
       $('#b').show();
      }

      $('#b').mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).hide();
      }

    })()
```

and in your css

```
#b {
  opacity: 0;
}
```